# Why are my confidence intervals much larger in glmmADMB than glmer.nb?

Tags: r, mixed-model, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, glmm

I'm plotting 3-way interaction terms from a negative binomial models, and tested the models in two packages to check my work and as a sensitivity analysis. I used the effect function to extract the fit and CIs to plot.

```
library(lme4)
model.lme <- glmer.nb(dv ~ condition * time * gender + (1 | id), 
                      family = nbinom(), data = df)

effect.out.lme <- effect(term = "condition * time * gender", 
                         xlevels = list(condition = c(0, 1), 
                                        gender = c(1, 2)), 
                         mod = model.lme)

library(glmmadmb)
model.admb <- glmmadmb(dv ~ condition * time * gender + (1 | id), 
                       data = df, family = nbinom2(), 
                       zeroInflation = FALSE) 

effect.out.admb <- effect(term = "condition * time * gender", 
                          xlevels = list(condition = c(0, 1), 
                                         gender = c(1, 2)), 
                          mod = model.admb)
```

When I examined the fitted values to plot, the estimates from `glmer.nb()` were in the expected range for the scale of the DV. However, the confidence intervals from `glmmadmb()` included negative values, and the fit estimates were much smaller than what would be expected given the range of the scale, so I assumed they were log transformed and exponentiated them. This got me fit estimates that were generally similar to those from `glmer.nb()`, but the `glmmadmb()` confidence intervals are much, much wider than those from `glmer.nb()`, and overlap substantially with each other when I graph them.

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to see what is going on without having the data to try ourselves. But I would suggest that you also compare your results using the **GLMMadaptive** and the **glmmTMB** packages. The former fits the same model using the adaptive Gaussian quadrature that provides a better approximation to the integrals over the random effects than the Laplace approximation used by the other packages.

Comment: Here is some sample data: https://gofile.io/?c=iUdoTH

I actually had tried with both of those packages but was unable to extract the fit using the effects function. 

GLMMadaptive gave me this the error: "Error in effects::Effect.default(focal.predictors, mod, ..., sources = args) : Effect plots are not implemented for families with more than one parameter in the variance function (e.g., negitave binomials)." 

glmmTMB gave me this error: "Error in mod.matrix %*% scoef : non-conformable arguments"

Comment: In **GLMMadaptive** you can use the `effectPlotData()` function instead - for more info check here: https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods_MixMod.html#effect-plots

Comment: I'll try that. I just noticed an error in the data I uploaded; use this instead: https://gofile.io/?c=ICiriN